# Optimizing my JAVA code snippet: args[] program input statement

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, arguments

So I'm trying to see if there is a "better" way to optimize the way I am writing this little piece of code snippet.

Right now, my piece of snippet is this:

```
private static LocalDate runDate = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // assuming we use 2 arguments (first is the testing environment we want, and
    // second is the date in MM-dd-yyyy format)
    if (args.length == 0) {
        throw new Exception("Not enough arguments in main.  Must provide at least the environment.");

    } else if (args.length == 2) {
        String[] dateArray = args[1].toString().split("-");
        runDate = LocalDate.of(Integer.parseInt(dateArray[2]), Integer.parseInt(dateArray[0]),
                Integer.parseInt(dateArray[1]));

    }

    if (runDate == null) {
        runDate = LocalDate.now();
    }
}
```

The input statement for my program arguments in run configuration is either `"TEST" "11-30-2020"` or just `"TEST"`.

As you can see from the code, I check if the length of my args is either 0 or 2 (and technically 1, which I will explain why soon). If there are 0 arguments, then throw an error because you at least need the environment to be working in. If there is 1 argument, which means JUST the environment `"TEST" (or PROD)`, then it means that the run date is `LocalDate.now()`, which takes the current date in yyyy-mm-dd format.

However, i also made it allow a run date for this program, where you can enter a run date in the format of mm-dd-yyyy and since there HAS to be a `"TEST"` argument, this checks off the else if statement and makes run date equal to the inputted arg date in the format of yyyy-mm-dd.

However, I'm not sure if this code is 100% good but the fact that it checks if runDate = null makes me feel a bit weird about it. What would be a better way to sort of handle these conditionals?

Comment: don't do that check, just instead of saying runDate = null; put runDate = LocalDate.now();

Comment: hmm, wouldn't that overwrite runDate = LocalDate.of(Integer.parseInt(dateArray[2]), Integer.parseInt(dateArray[0]), Integer.parseInt(dateArray[1])); if there is an inputted date for the args? OR did you mean if (runDate == LocalDate.now()) {runDate == LocalDate.now()}? This would made more sense, but just out of curiosity, would there be a cleaner way?

Comment: no. your runDate = LocalDate.of ... would overwrite the runDate = LocalDate.now() if there's a value to overwrite it with. Don't change the location of the assignment of the runDate, just the value of the original assignment

Comment: oh you mean, I should write runDate = LocalDate.now() as the very first line, before the conditionals right? That way IF there is args.length of 2, then it can be overwritten?

Comment: Dumb of me my bad, I forgot I had it as a static variable up top, i can just do it as the original private LocalDate runDate = LocalDate.now()